# How to construct shape functions in the $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: finite-element

It is necessary for me to find the shape functions on $L^2(\Omega)$(piecewise constant functions),
I searched a lot but that, could not find anything, all of them are about higher degree polynomial.
If we define the space as follow:
$${\cal Dp0}=\{v \in L^2(\Omega):v|_T \in {\cal p0(T)}, \forall T \in {\cal T}\}$$ 
where ${\cal T}$ is triangulation of the domain.
How can I find them?

Comment: This is essentially what Finite Volume Method consists of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$p_0(T)$ is the space of all functions that are *constant* on cell $T$. The shape function that corresponds to this is the function that is 1 on cell $T$ and zero everywhere else. Its derivative is then obviously zero in the cell itself, as well as outside the cell, but it is undefined at the interface.

Comment: @Rosa, Wolfgang's point about cells is that you need to discretize $\Omega$ into a finite number of subregions, usually called elements or cells. Triangles, in two dimensions, are popular.

Comment: Ah, yes, the question originally included this information. Yes, $T$ are the cells of a mesh.

Comment: sorry for removing it, I added some information on it again.